# How can I remove npm module manually?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-start

I have a newly installed Windows and it seems that all the system variables are wrong. I can not remove npm and reinstall it.
In either case, both the removal of npm and installation, I'd receive

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\'c:'`

This shows that my system variable is wrong. I tried to correct it but I'd get the same error.

How can I remove npm manually?

I was expecting that my system variable would work accordingly, But it does not.

Comment: for those with a similar issue, i found how to solve it through this resource http://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/a-note-on-permissions.html